# Editar archivo python

Tags: python

Necesito hacer un pequeño programa en python para editar un archivo con permisos de superuser. Creo que es bastante sencillo pero nunca he trabajado con gestión de archivos en python.

Tengo un archivo que según una entrada o valor de una variable, tendría que quitar comentario una línea (delete //), y comentar otra (add //). Este archivo permite configurar otro pequeño programa.

Muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda y  comentarios.

Saludos,

daniel

Comment: Hola Daniel y bienvenido a [es.so]. En este sitio ofrecemos ayuda, sí, pero si tú nos enseñas qué has intentado. Por tanto, investiga un poco, prueba algo y luego plantea tus dudas específicas.

Comment: Python no puede elevarse a sí mismo los permisos, pero lo puedes hacer desde fuera al lanzar el comando. Simplemente escribe un programa python "normal" que haga con el fichero lo que pretendes, y luego ejecuta el script con `sudo python script.py`

Comment: Hola, perfecto. Probaré, tal y cómo dices. Gracias por la aportación.

Answer (score 1):

Finalmente, investigando y probando algunas soluciones me quedo con esta:

def replace_line(file_name, line_num, text):

```
lines = open(file_name, 'r').readlines()
lines[line_num] = text
out = open(file_name, 'w')
out.writelines(lines)
out.close()
```

replace_line('/home/pi/test.txt', 5, 'Linea 5\n') ##sobrescribe en la linea 5**

Mejor sobrescribir linea que intentar borrar y insertar // de los comentarios.

Gracias!

Saludos,

daniel